# Django querying models with foreignkey

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, python-3.7

I am creating a project of customer management, in this I want to query some models which are related with foreign key.

I have created these models.

```
from django.db import models


class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

    # to get name as string on behalf of "Customer Object 1" in DB.
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Product(models.Model):
    # To make a dropdown menu to choose category.
    CATEGORY = (
        ('Indoor', 'Indoor'),
        ('Out Door', 'Out Door'),
    )

    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    price = models.FloatField(null=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, choices=CATEGORY)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
class Order(models.Model):
    # To make a dropdown menu to choose status.
    STATUS = (
        ('Pending', 'Pending'),
        ('Out for Delivery', 'Out for Delivery'),
        ('Delivered', 'Delivered'),
    )

    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, null=True,
                                 on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, null=True,
                                on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, choices=STATUS)
```

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import *


def home(request):
    customers = Customer.objects.all()
    orders = Order.objects.all()

    total_customers = customers.count()
    total_orders = orders.count()
    delivered = orders.filter(status='Delivered').count()
    pending = orders.filter(status='Pending').count()

    front_end_stuff = {'customers': customers, 'orders': orders,
                       'total_customers': total_customers, 'total_orders': total_orders,
                       'delivered': delivered, 'pending': pending,
                       }

    return render(request, 'accounts/dashboard.html', context=front_end_stuff)


def products(request):
    products_ = Product.objects.all()

    return render(request, 'accounts/products.html', context={'products': products_})


def customer(request, pk):
    customers = Customer.objects.filter(id=pk)
    orders = Order.objects.filter(id=pk)
    customer_products = Product.objects.filter(id=pk)

    total_orders = orders.count()

    front_end_stuff = {'customers': customers, 'orders': orders,
                       'total_orders': total_orders, 'customer_products': customer_products
                       }

    return render(request, 'accounts/customer.html', context=front_end_stuff)
```

I want to get status of the orders placed by a specific customer, also i have set the dynamic urls for getting customer profile view page and in it i want to loop through it and print out the status in respective field.

I have attached the image of customer profile view page where i want the data.

[customer_profile_view_page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsrIn.png)

I tried one query which i found on internet is :

```
customers = Customer.objects.filter(id=pk)
status = customers.order_set.all()
```

but I get an error

> AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'order_set'

I am using :

- Windows 10,
- Python 3.7,
- Django 3.0.7.

Comment: You are trying to fetch all the orders status of a specific customer, right?

Answer (score 0):

To get the list of all the orders of a customer, you can try -

```
# this will give the list of orders for customer with id = pk
orders = Order.objects.filter(customer__id=pk) # it's a double underscore
```

You can iterate each order to fetch the status -

```
for order in orders:
    print(order.status)
```

Or with what you tried, use `.get` instead of `.filter`.

```
customer = Customer.objects.get(id=pk) # the customer has to be present with this id else it will give an exception.
orders = customer.order_set.all()
```

[Doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward)

Comment: thanks Ejaz, i tried this and it worked perfectly fine, thank you for your help.